# How to use SELECTED with array filled select form

Tags: php, html

Here is my code.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT product_name FROM products');
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $products[] = array('product_name' => $row['product_name']);
    }

<select name="products" id="products">
  <option name="search_product" value="All Products"<?php if (isset($search_product_selected) AND $sort_product_selected == "All Products") { echo ' SELECTED'; } ?>> All Products</option>
 <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
  <option name="search_product" value="<?php echo $product['product_name'];"><?php echo $product['product_name']; ?></option>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

This is part of a form that reloads the same page, adjusting the items shown on the page. The form works perfectly, and the search works perfectly, but how do I use SELECTED to highlight which product was selected in the previous search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the value with your search word, if they are equal then put `selected` into the option.

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
  <option name="search_product" value="<?php echo $product['product_name'];?>"<?php echo $product['product_name'] === $_POST['search_key'] : ' selected' : '' ?>><?php echo $product['product_name']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I am getting this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';'"

Comment: @jotty should be `echo $product['product_name'] === $_POST['search_key'] ? ' selected' : '';` -> `?` in place of the 1st `:`

Comment: Works beautifully. Bonus: I understand why! (I'm new to this). Thank you both very much.